# Site flashes intermediate 'Redirecting to ...' page

Tags: redirection, performance

On a local development site an intermediate 'Redirecting to ...' page flashes for a second before rendering the correct page. This seems to be happening at various places, even on cron run page.

The culprit may be slow page load. On web profiler I briefly spot a 303 response before the correct page is displayed. Is there a way to fix/debug this?